# add hash query parameter to URL with time limit laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url, hash

I want to add a hash query parameter to my app `URL` which should have ids and a time limit, let's say 3 minutes. If we try to use the same URL after 3 minutes it should work. How can I do this?

```
use Hash;
...
$id = 15;
$key = base64_encode(Hash::make($id));
echo "http://someurl?send_mail_to_user=$id&key=$key";
```

I have tried the above which works, but we can pass only one `id` and it didn't have a time limit option.

Can Anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has [built-in support](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#signed-urls) for signing URL's even with time limitation.

You can easily do something like the following instead to achieve something that you can easily validate that also supports time limiting:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

return URL::signedRoute('your_route_name', now()->addMinutes(30), ['id' => 15]);
```

You can then validate that the request is valid and signed for (and within the time limit) like so:

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/send_mail_to_user', function (Request $request) {
    if (! $request->hasValidSignature()) {
        abort(401);
    }

    // ...
})->name('your_route_name');
```

Comment: Tnx for your quick response. But my URL are in a blade files like  `<a href="{{$app->url}}/home"`. For this, I want to add hash. How Can I do this? What I thought is will generate a hash ID and attach it to a URL like `<a href="{{$app->url}}/home?hash={{$app->hash}}"`. Any idea?

Comment: You just pass the result of `URL::signedRoute(...)` as a variable to your view - the same way you would pass any kind of data to a view.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is generate your `temporarySignedRoute` and then pass it to your view. As an example;

**web.php**

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    // generate the signed route and pass it to the welcome view
    $route = URL::temporarySignedRoute('verify', now()->addMinutes(10), ['user' => 15]);
    return view('welcome', ['route' => $route]);
});

// define the route which will handle requests using the signed route
Route::get('/verify/{user}', function (Request $request) {
    if (! $request->hasValidSignature()) {
        // request is not valid
        abort(401);
    }
    // otherwise request is valid
})->name('verify');
```

**welcome.blade.php**

```html
<a href="{{ $route }">Verify</a>
```

The `value` of `$route` in the above will be that of the `temporarySignedRoute`.

The above call all be moved to controllers, I just used the `web.php` file to keep it simple for this example.